# at command not responding on sim800L and arduino uno

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, sim800

I would like to ask around SIM800L EVB module to sending message using Arduino UNO  R3 DIP/SMD CH340. i change the pin tx/rx from 2, 3 vice versa, 7,8 the result either not displaying anything or anytext, the serial monitor just displaying AT no respon from the SIM800L EVB module. pls enlighten me. thank you

Schematic for both describe below:

SIM800L EVB:[image: SIM800L EVB]

Arduino UNO  R3 DIP/SMD CH340:[image: Arduino UNO R3 DIP/SMD CH340]

AT Command not displaying anything/anytext:[image: AT Command not displaying anything/anytext]

The code from [here](https://www.proyekrumahan.id/2017/08/belajar-arduino-sim800l-sebagai-sms.html) I modified the pin as below

```
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"

SoftwareSerial SMS_Gateway(0, 1); // Rx | Tx
char tempChar = "";

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Testing the SIM800 Module");

  SMS_Gateway.begin(115200);

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Serial.print("=====");
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Starting Connection");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if (SMS_Gateway.available()) {
    tempChar = SMS_Gateway.read();
    Serial.write(tempChar);
  }

  if (Serial.available()) {
    tempChar = Serial.read();
    SMS_Gateway.write(tempChar);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post to use Markdown to show images inline instead of linking to them.

Comment: @MaxvonHippel sorry i dont understand, anyway i just tried to put "!" in the front of the image, stackoverflow notification at least 10 reputation to show image....

Comment: Fair enough, it's fine as it is in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your images I see that you wired the Arduino Rx to the SIM800 Rx and the same for the Tx but the color is hard to see. You need to wire the Arduino Rx to the Sim800 Tx and the Arduino Tx to the Sim800 Rx. This means that the command send (Tx) by the Arduino is received (Rx by the SIM800) and visa versa.

Also connect your Arduino Gnd to the SIM800 Gnd unless you are sure they share their ground through the power supply.

The SIM800 automatically matches baudrates so keep sending AT commands until you get a OK back.

Comment: do same thing as your instruction...swapping the tx, rx also put gnd on both and keep trying send at command. but no result.

is there any way to check the module work or defect?
read from google just watching the blink led rate..
if blink fast then slow than the modul is work

second way using UART (i dont have this tool).

any technique can use to check wheter the module work or defect. thank you...

Comment: ignore my previous reply...according your instruction...and i do some test...change to pin 2,3 i got ok reply....thank you gerhard for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your baudrate to 9600